# Can jQuery click events be unbound or reset?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, memory-leaks

I've discovered a resource leak on a webpage I'm working on.

This webpage has two textfields, that upon click show a modal dialog, perform a data request to the backend, and then present that information in a table that the user can select an entry from for use in the textbox they originally clicked.

I'm binding the click events to the textboxes like so:

```
var $field = $('#one-of-the-text-fields');

$field.click(function () {
        App.DialogClass.show();
        App.DialogClass.PopulateTable();
        App.DialogClass.GotoPageButtonAction(actionArgs);  // Offender!
});
```

...Which calls...

```
App.DialogClass = (function($) {

var pub {},
    $gotoPage = $('#pageNumberNavigationField'),
    $gotoPageButton = $('#pageNumberNavigationButton');

// ...SNIP unimportant other details...

pub.GotoPageButtonAction = function (args) {
    $gotoPageButton.click(function () {
        var pageNumber = $gotoPage.val();
        pub.PopulateTable(args);   // Breakpoint inserted here...
    });
};

return pub;

})(jQuery);
```

I noticed the leak because when I ran through using Chrome's JavaScript debugger, I'm always having one extra breakpoint hit every time I click a different button (e.g. the first time I click field A, the breakpoint is hit twice.  When I hit field B after that, the break point is hit three times.  If I click A after *that*, the breakpoint is hit four times.  Extrapolate as necessary.)

Nowhere in my code am I doing anything about an existing click event for a given field.  I suspect my leak stems from the fact that the events are not getting cleaned up.  That being said, I am also not terribly familiar with JavaScript/jQuery.  What are some techniques for removing click events from a control?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: .unbind() ? http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) on newer jquery version

Comment: If using jQuery 1.7+, you should use `on()` and `off()` for this, but the problem is probably that you are binding the click inside a function that runs several times, binding the click over and over, as that tends to cause this exact problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. Just unbind them:

```
$field.unbind('click');
```

However, bear in mind that this will remove *all* event handlers for click, not just yours. For safety, you should use namespaces when binding handlers:

```
$field.bind('click.mynamespace', function(){
    // do something
});
```

Then,

```
$field.unbind('click.mynamespace');
```

So, then, only your handler will be removed.

Answer (score 4):

If you have used **.bind()** to bind them **.unbind()** removes the events

If you have used **.on()** to bind them **.off()** removes the events

Comment: "As of jQuery 3.0, [.unbind()](https://api.jquery.com/unbind/#unbind) has been deprecated. It was superseded by the [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged."

Answer (score 1):

JQuery offers the [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) function to unbind event listeners.

Note that you may also do it in vanilla JS using [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.removeEventListener).

But instead of unbinding, you probably should not bind each time in `GotoPageButtonAction` : once is enough.

Comment: Because of the nature of the paging system I'm working on, I have to perform a rebind, as the request in the backend is dependent on the field clicked.  I would not normally perform a rebind on click, but this case is a one-off.