# Jquery doesn't work on appended content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 jquery functions for loading "next step" and "previous step". they go like this :

**Next Step Jquery Function:**

```
    $(".continue-btn").on("click",".next-step",function(){
         //somthing
    }
```

**Previous Step Jquery Function:**

```
    $(".continue-btn").on("click",".previous-step",function(){
         //somthing
    }
```

These 2 functions load my next and previous jquery contents well, but in the new jquery content don't work.

**My html page loaded by jquery function**

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="cell-12">
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-large main-bg AddAddress">Add</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And I have a jquery function for adding parameters like this:

```
      $(".cell-12").on("click",".AddAddress",function(){ 
         //Somthing
      }
```

where is the problem?

Comment: what or where is .cell-12?  more HTML could be usefull

Comment: edit my question with .cell-12 div @reyaner

Comment: is this div also loaded with the content?

Comment: yes another div : before cell-12 : <div class="row"> @reyaner

Comment: Bind the click event on `.row` instead of `cell-12`

Comment: I have another function that doesn't work also : $('.table-style2').on("click",".remove-item",function(){//somthing}) @reyaner

Comment: i'll try this solution but doesn't work @ShaunakD

Comment: try to change  $('.table-style2').on("click",".remove-item",function() to $(document).on('click', '.remove-item', function()

Comment: i'll do this and $('body') , but doesn't work this solution , @ntaloventi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".cell-12").on("click",".AddAddress",function(){ 
         //Somthing
      }
```

The first question you need to ask yourself is *"Does `.cell-12` exist when I run that line?"*

Seeing that you dynamically add the html content, your initial `$('.cell-12')` doesn't contain anything.. because it doesn't yet exist. Even if you add that class in the future, the jquery `onclick` event won't be updated with your new elements (because it only contains the elements at the time it was called).

Which leads you to two choices.

**A)** You add the onclick event to the document which will find all your elements with your `.AddAdress` class

```
$(document).on("click",".AddAddress", function(){

});
```

**B)**

You reset all your on click events every time you add more content. Here is a stackoverflow post talking about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625919/can-jquery-click-events-be-unbound-or-reset)

---

Additional information:

You might of heard something called `.live`

> Description: Attach an event handler for all elements which match the
>   current selector, now and in the future.

But that was deprecated due to performance issues.

Comment: Never use `body` as the default for for delegated events. It has a bug to do with styling. Use `document` as the default.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie thanks for the tip. I did not know that. I'll update my post.

Comment: about $('body') and $(document), i'll try both of theme but doesn't work. and about solution B, i'll must test it. thanks for your time. @grimbode

Answer (score -1):

The container you are using as parent, have to be there on page load:
for example:

```
<div class="row">
  //content loaded with ajax...
</div>
```

and then this should work

```
 $(".row").on("click",".AddAddress",function(){ 
         //Somthing
   }
```

Comment: no, i'll try this solution but doesn't  work @reyaner